# Is it safe to use std::list as a circular list?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, std

So incrementing or decrementing the end() iterator is defined in the standard? On linux, the begin() is implemented as end()++.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::list<int> numbers;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    numbers.push_back(i);

  auto it = numbers.begin();
  int count = 3;
  while (count)
  {
    std::cout << *it++;
    if (it == numbers.end())
    {
      ++it; // is this ok ???
      --count;
      std::cout << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

So the output always the same on every platform?

Output:

```
0123456789
0123456789
0123456789
```

Comment: Change that `++it;` to `it = numbers.begin();` and you have defined behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Incrementing the iterator returned from `end()` of any of the standard C++ library containers results in undefined behavior. Due to an implementation detail common to most implementations of `std::list<T>` it may work to increment `list.end()` but there is no guarantee that it does.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not ok. The `std::list` iterator is a [BidirectionalIterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/BidirectionalIterator.html), which is a refinement of [ForwardIterator](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ForwardIterator.html). The precondition for both `++i` and `i++` for a ForwardIterator states:

> `i` is dereferenceable

which does not hold for `end()` as it points *past* the last item of the list.